# SQL - Unique Values By Hour

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, hour

I have a table `VISITS` where I want to look at all `DEVICES` and get a unique count of `USERS` by HOUR each DAY `([parsed from TIME 2014-05-01 07:01:04)`. After an hour, the `USER` could be part of another HOUR of that day.

So, the output should show:

```
DAY     HOUR   DEVICE   USERS
3/1/15   0       Dev1     240
3/1/15   0       Dev2     123
...
3/1/15   23      Dev1      43
3/2/15  ....
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask]. Please show table schema, data types, and sample data.

Comment: And RDBMS you're working with.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY DAY, HOUR`

Comment: Working with MySQL. 
TABLE is VISITS
Columns are Device - varchar(17)
Users - varchar(17)
Date - datetime

I need to have the unique count of users per hour per device for a given date range, such as from 3/1/15 thru 3/31/15. So, each hr it would show all devices and unique counts per device.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without testing this (not sure if MySQL still requires backticks):

```
SELECT    Date(`time`)         as `day`, 
          Hour(`time`)         as `hour`, 
          device,
          count(DISTINCT user) as `users`
FROM      visits 
GROUP BY  Date(`time`), 
          Hour(`time`), 
          device;
```

Comment: I think it should be `SUM(users)`

Comment: I think that his input timestamp is the value, *time*, and what he has shown is the expected output.

Comment: I think OP also need an `ORDER BY` over fields too ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT day,hour,devices,COUNT(DISTINCT Users)
FROM Visits
GROUP BY day,hour,devices
ORDER BY day,hour,devices
```